# Why PHP code is not being processed?

Tags: php

I have a PHP page Read.php that echoes the contents of another php file, test.php.test.php contains some php codes but these codes are not processed in Read.php. They are copied as they are.

Read.php

```
<?php

    $text = 1;
    if ($text == 1){
        $file = file_get_Contents("test.php");
        echo $file;
    }
?>
```

test.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Text
            <?php echo "Manish";  echo $text;>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Source code of Read.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Text
            <?php echo "Manish";  echo $text;>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I make this php code process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    $text = 1;
    if ($text == 1){
        include('test.php');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read.php

```
<?php

$text = 1;
if($text == 1){
  include 'test.php';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve it from the web server (`http://...`) instead of from the filesystem. PHP is only processed if the web server processes it.

Comment: Well, technically `include()`ing or `require()`ing the file would also result in a similar behavior here.